# Android AppWidget customizable by user

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have a problem to make a customizable AppWidget : I don't know how to do... I tried to update appearance regularly with this function :

```
public static void updateApparence(Context context)
{
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < widgetLayoutIds.length ; i++)
    {
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, appWidgetProvidersClass[i]));

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), widgetLayoutIds[i]);

        views.setInt(R.id.widget_background,    "setBackgroundColor",   prefs.getInt(SettingsApparence.BACKGROUND_COLOR,    0xFFFFFFFF));
        views.setInt(R.id.matiere, "setTextColor", prefs.getInt(SettingsApparence.COULEUR_MATIERE, 0xFF666666));
        views.setInt(R.id.horaires, "setTextColor", prefs.getInt(SettingsApparence.COULEUR_HORAIRES, 0xFF888888));
        views.setInt(R.id.salle, "setTextColor", prefs.getInt(SettingsApparence.COULEUR_SALLE, 0xFF888888));

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(context.getFilesDir() + PATH_CLE);

        if(bm == null)
        {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.settings_icon);
            bm = changeImageColor(bm, prefs.getInt(SettingsApparence.COULEUR_CLE, 0xFF000000));
        }

        views.setBitmap(R.id.settings, "setImageBitmap", bm);


        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(context.getFilesDir() + PATH_CALENDRIER);

        if(bm == null)
        {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.calendrier_icon);
            bm = changeImageColor(bm, prefs.getInt(SettingsApparence.COULEUR_CALENDRIER, 0xFF000000));
        }

        views.setBitmap(R.id.emploi_du_temps, "setImageBitmap", bm);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, views);
    }
}
```

But sometimes, the original appearance (in R.layout.widget, in appWidgetProvidersClass[]) reappear...
How can I do that ?

Comment: what are the widget that you want to customize ?? TextView, actionBar, progressbar, ...

Comment: I would like to customize the entire widget (there are 3 textviews, 2 imageviews. The two images are not ressources, they are in the internal storage. I would also customize the backgound). Thanks !

Comment: Maybe I could create an XML file like a ressource, but in the internal storage, to modify it when the user wants to change appearence... But I don't know how to inflate it to a RemoteView

Comment: add advise you to visit this blog : https://blog.stylingandroid.com it will really help to improve your applications ;)

Comment: Thank you Fakher for this link, it's very interresting ! :-)
But is there an example of customizable widget in this blog ? I did not see one

Comment: i didn't see !! u can check ;)

Comment: I think I misspoke : I would like to create a widget customizable by the user, not by creator...

Comment: I solved the problem !! Finally, I modify the RemoteViews as a global variable, and I update my appWidget with it, and it works ! Thanks !